# How can I convert a whole XML dump from Wikia to Kindle?

Tags: xml, kindle, mediawiki

I'd like to convert an XML dump of whole Deus Ex Wikia to my Kindle. How can I do that?

Here's the compressed XML file if anyone wants to try their solutions before posting an answer:
http://dumps.wikia.net/e/en/endeusex/pages_current.xml.gz

Comment: If not on Windows, you could maybe try using Mobipocket in Wine. About your xml file : It's in a very specific format, so I doubt that any ready-made tool will do the work. You might have to write a converter to some known format that is accepted by calibre (which is simply the world's most extensive converter).

Comment: I think the same, but before I jump to programming, I preferred to ask. Perhaps somebody already solved this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it without too much effort. I've set up my own Mediawiki installation and imported the XML (I needed to increase the limits in PHP configuration - the ones concering the maximum execution time and uploaded file size). It took quite a lot of time on my netbook. On the result page, I could copy the list of the pages, then use `egrep -v` to filter out non-content pages, such as user profiles, discussions, templates etc.

Then I installed [EPubExport](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EPubExport). I visited `Special:EpubPrint`page and copied the filtered-out list of pages there. Generating the ebook took ages and then converting the EPUB to .mobi was another two hours. The output file is suspiciously long (I doubt that users wrote as much content as Mitchell did in "Cloud Atlas" book), but judging from the preview, it looks legit. It lacks images because they weren't in the XML, though. I'll read it once I'll have some more spare time and let you know how it worked in the long run. If you want to read the ebook by yourself, it can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0l3jx9g6lm66sy3/y54gcf8F_r). You'll need to jump to the "Deus Ex" article, because I forgot to cut the index page from the output file.

Comment: Too bad I can't award the bounty to myself.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can do this with [Mobipocket](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/HomePage/default.asp?Language=EN).

[Building from XML](http://www.mobipocket.com/dev/article.asp?basefolder=prcgen&file=building.htm#xml)

Comment: Haven't tried yet. Would need some Windows box to run it.

Comment: Help in testing if it works is appreciated ;)

Comment: Well, I finally read the documentation and it appears that to build the book I'd also need some XSL code. Bearing in mind that the XML contains Wikimedia markup, I don't think it'd be the easiest approach.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your Wiki system, but if it can export to PDF instead of XML,
then [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) is one tool that can convert pdf to almost any ebook format.

Comment: The solution sucks. You usually don't want to mess with with pdf unless it really is the only possible solution.

Comment: calibre handles pdf like any other format and will not take hours to do the job. So what's the problem with pdf?

Comment: Never knew before? Read up on manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html, section "Convert PDF documents".

Comment: PDF files can be horribly complex, but simple ones are no problem. If you post the PDF export of your wiki, I'll have a go at it with calibre.